# Path error in Grunt/Webpack/Babel

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm toying with ES6 modules for the first time, trying to get basic bundling going with Webpack. I'd like to use use Babel 6 (currently the latest and greatest) for transpiling in the Webpack loader. I've read [this](http://www.2ality.com/2015/04/webpack-es6.html) and [this](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/) and [this](https://medium.com/@malyw/how-to-update-babel-5-x-6-x-d828c230ec53#.69xty46om).

package.json includes:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "~6.0.12",
    "babel-core": "~6.0.12",
    "babel-loader": "~6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.14",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-webpack": "^1.0.11",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.1"
  },
```

file structure:

```
myproject
├── js
│   ├── es6
│   │   ├── app.js
│   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   ├── lib1.js
│   │   │   ├── lib2.js
│   │   └── modules
│   │       └── _myModule.js
├── node_modules
├── index.html
├── gruntfile.js
```

gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        webpack: {
            options: {
                entry: "./js/es6/app.js",
                output: {
                    path: __dirname,
                    filename: "webpacked.js",
                },
                module : {
                    loaders: [
                        {

       // grunt --verbose says the problem is with the next line
                            include: path.resolve(__dirname, "es6"),
                            loader: 'babel',    
                            query: {
                                presets: ['es2015']
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                failOnError: true,
                resolve: {
                    root: [ "js", "node_modules" ],
                }       
            },
            build : {
                devtool: "sourcemap",
                debug: true
            }
        },

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('babel');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('babel-core');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('babel-loader');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('babel-preset-es2015');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-minify-html');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-webpack');    
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['webpack']);
};
```

I'm obviously missing something really basic with path handling. I can't even get started, and I've gone in circles for hours, trying lots of combinations. Error is:

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> ReferenceError: path is not defined
```

Any help very appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing

```
include: path.resolve(__dirname, "es6"),
```

and using the `path` module, but you have not loaded it.

```
var path = require('path');
```

Comment: :) Thank you. Now I am getting the error "Module parse failed: myproject/js/es6/app.js Line 1: Unexpected token: 'import Fling from Fling.js' You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type." It seems like the transpiling Babel loader is only set up to work on modules, not on the ES6 "import" code in the app.js "entry" file itself. How can I transpile the entry "app.js" file at the very beginning of the build, while still just using Webpack?

Comment: `include` needs to match any ES6 files, so if you've got one outside your `es6` folder, you'll need to expand `include` to also match that.